# Why is my text is not being rendered before an F5 on the page?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

The problem: the currency and the % of this gauge chart only render after a F5 on the page. Why is that happening?

First time accessing the page:
[image: Currency and percentage not being rendered]

After F5:
[image: OK]

**chartExample.html**

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Target" icon-name="utility:chart">
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <div>   
                <canvas id="gaugechart" lwc:dom="manual"></canvas>
                <div id="percentage" style="font-size: 15px;"></div>
                <span id="gauge-value" style="font-size: 15px;"></span>
            </div>
            <div if:false={isChartJsInitialized} class="slds-col--padded slds-size--1-of-1">
                Gauge chart not loaded =/
            </div>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**chartExample.js**

```
loadChart() {
        console.log("loadChart() chamado");
        this.el = this.template.querySelector("span");
    
        Promise.all([loadScript(this, gaugechart)])
          .then(() => {
            this.isChartJsInitialized = true;
            let target = this.template.querySelector("canvas");
    
            // staticLabels
            this.config.staticLabels.labels[1] = this.targetEvt / 4;
            this.config.staticLabels.labels[2] = this.targetEvt / 2;
            this.config.staticLabels.labels[3] = (this.targetEvt * 3) / 4;
            this.config.staticLabels.labels[4] = this.targetEvt;
    
            // staticZones
            this.config.staticZones[0].max = this.targetEvt / 4;
    
            this.config.staticZones[1].min = this.targetEvt / 4 + 1;
            this.config.staticZones[1].max = this.targetEvt / 2;
    
            this.config.staticZones[2].min = this.targetEvt / 2 + 1;
            this.config.staticZones[2].max = (this.targetEvt * 3) / 4;
    
            this.config.staticZones[3].min = (this.targetEvt * 3) / 4 + 1;
            this.config.staticZones[3].max = this.targetEvt;
    
            let gauge = new Gauge(target).setOptions(this.config);
    
            Gauge.prototype.paddingBottom = 0.3;
            gauge.maxValue = this.targetEvt;
            gauge.setMinValue(0);
            gauge.animationSpeed = 32;
            gauge.set(this.amount);
            let textRenderer = new TextRenderer(
              this.template.querySelector("span")
            );
            textRenderer.render = (gauge) => {
              this.el.innerHTML = `${this.currency} ${gauge.value.toLocaleString(
                "en-GB"
              )} (${((gauge.value / gauge.maxValue) * 100).toFixed(2)}%)`;
              console.log("rendered");
            };
            gauge.setTextField(textRenderer);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            this.dispatchEvent(
              new ShowToastEvent({
                title: "Error loading gauge.js",
                message: error.message,
                variant: "error"
              })
            );
          });
      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know for sure, but I imagine you're attempting to edit the html content of `<span id="gauge-value" style="font-size: 15px;"></span>`, but you haven't set `lwc:dom="manual"` on it.

Not sure why you're trying to directly manipulate the DOM for this.

I'd try replacing `<span id="gauge-value" style="font-size: 15px;"></span>` with:

```
<template if:true={gaugeText}>
    <span style="font-size: 15px;">{gaugeText}</span>
</template>
```

and update your code to set a variable.

e.g.

replace

```
let textRenderer = new TextRenderer(
  this.template.querySelector("span")
);
textRenderer.render = (gauge) => {
  this.el.innerHTML = `${this.currency} ${gauge.value.toLocaleString(
    "en-GB"
  )} (${((gauge.value / gauge.maxValue) * 100).toFixed(2)}%)`;
  console.log("rendered");
};
```

with

```
this.gaugeText = `${this.currency} ${gauge.value.toLocaleString("en-GB")} (${((gauge.value / gauge.maxValue) * 100).toFixed(2)}%)`;
```

where `gaugeText` is a variable you add to your js.